# error using environment in Spyder (Python 3.8)

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, python-3.8, virtual-environment, anaconda3

I have upload a new environment in anaconda and selected it as my new Python interpreter... However, I obtained the following error:

```
Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 1.9.2 and < 1.10.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.

You can install it by running in a system terminal:

conda install spyder‑kernels

or

pip install spyder‑kernels
```

I have done the conda and pip in the terminal and said packages installed... but the error continues appearing...any idea?

Comment: when installing spyder-kernels, did you make sure the package is installed to the correct Python environment?

Comment: I installed the package using the terminal from that Python environment

Comment: I think the problem is with the version of Spyder, how can I update it?