# An error occurred while starting the kernel in Spyder

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, spyder

I have been trying to get my Spyder console to stop this error on my Mac Big Sur. I am not sure if there an issue with the version and interpreter I am using, but I am not sure how to switch to another version or have the correct version.

> Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the
> spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 2.0.1
> and < 2.1.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create
> a console for you.
>
> You can install it by running in a system terminal:
>
> conda install spyder‑kernels=2.0
>
> or
>
> pip install spyder‑kernels==2.0.*

I have tried both commands in terminal but they fail to download

Comment: Can you provide the error messages when you try both commands?

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68440517/10197418